# Vuforia Model Target status

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing an application with Unity using Vuforia. I am using a camera to recognize a model target. I would like to be able to save the tracking position when the target is detected and restore it when tracking is lost.

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with this functionality and could help me understand how to implement a script correctly.

I would greatly appreciate any advice, suggestions, or code examples you could provide.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with restoring the tracking position? Do you want vuforia to start tracking again? Do you want to avoid showing the model target guide view?

Comment: when I lose tracking I still want to show the object in the last recognized position

Comment: [Extended tracking](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/environments/device-tracking#extended-tracking-1) sounds like what you are looking for